# Visual Studio Private gallery atom.xml throws error while accessing from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Error while Trying to create a private visual studio extension gallery.

I have a vsix file which is ready to be shipped to everyone in the organisation.I have generated the atom.xml(using openly available tools).

when i store the atom.xml file in my local machine and provide the local path in the extension in visual studio it works fine and i can see the extension  in the visual studio.

But since the local path of my machine is not accessible to everyone in my organization i uploaded both Vsix and atom file into the git hub repository of the organisation.

When provided this git link where atom.xml resides it throws error as below
" For Security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document.To enable DTD proessing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method"

Intially thought this could be because of wrongly built xml. But the same XML does not create any problem when stored in local path and accessed through extensions gallery from visual studio

Already tried accessing the atom.xml file from local machine path and shows up no error. but when the same xml is uploaded to a organization git, it throws up the above error

Here is the atom.xml file through which i am trying to access the vsix file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text"></title>
  <id>86581393-7E84-4D3C-AB43-C519146CD947</id>
  <updated>2019-09-26T11:29:40+05:30</updated>
  <generator>VSGallery.AtomGenerator</generator>
  <entry>
    <id>cddba304-d16f-446e-b3a3-94d26d952189</id>
    <title type="text">Trace</title>
    <summary type="text">Visual Studio extension for Trace </summary>
    <published>2019-09-25T06:11:31Z</published>
    <updated>2019-09-25T06:11:31Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>SJ</name>
    </author>
    <content type="application/octet-stream" src="https://github.xxx.com/Visual-Studio-extension/blob/master/trace.vsix" />
    <Vsix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010" xmlns:xsi="    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Id>cddba304-d16f-446e-b3a3-94d26d952189</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <References></References>
      <Rating xsi:nil="true"></Rating>
      <RatingCount xsi:nil="true"></RatingCount>
      <DownloadCount xsi:nil="true"></DownloadCount>
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

[Here is the how i have added the private extension gallery in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hikXF.png)

[This is the error which i receive when i try to access the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnMNh.png)

Comment: Can [this document](https://www.koskila.net/fixing-security-reasons-dtd-prohibited-xml-document-issue/) make some help?

Comment: No luck with this as well. i disabled IPV6, still no go.